# Can I post this on Familysearch?

Tags: familysearch.org

So, I was doing some Family History at my local Family History Center when I came across newspaper articles on NewspaperArchive.com concerning some events that happened to ancestors I was researching. One of them was concerning the murder trial of which one of my ancestors was the victim, and the other a short paragraph about how another ancestor was arrested for seduction.

To ask, is it acceptable to even think about putting a screenshot or a transcription of the article to their respective ancestors without violating copyright? If so, are those stories OK for FamilySearch? I know that there are certain limitations that are there that keep the high quality of memories in FamilySearch.

Comment: In essence, this is the same question as http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/10207/1006.  Please read the terms and conditions at NewspaperArchive.com or other sites where you find these materials.

Comment: Yes, the Terms and Conditions did help with posting, but what about the appropriateness of the articles?

Comment: Only you can decide the appropriateness of publishing the articles. Something to consider is do direct ancestors of these individuals know about the incidents, how recent are they and are they likely to be upset if they read them. As you have asked the question I suspect you have some misgivings and so you should listen to those. However, those stories are in the public domain and are freely available.

Comment: I think this question could be improved -- asking about the appropriateness of posting information (and linking to the prior terms-and-conditions question) would allow you to split the two issues and have one question per question.  Also: gentle reminder (to myself as well as everyone else here) that we should avoid answering questions in the comments.